# spring-data-redis 2.x using RedisTemplate with RedisCacheManager and redisson for the connectionfactory

Tags: spring-data-redis

How do I define  a RedisCacheManager using the properties of a RedisTemplate?

My application does not have @Cacheable-related annotations since it is using the RedisTemplate.

Since spring-data-redis 2.x, the constructor for RedisCacheManager has changed from using RedisOperations to RedisCacheWriter.

Will I still need to define a RedisCacheManager?
Do you have an example?

I tried to instrument some work-around but I do not see any hits.

I have this method:

```
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                     final Map<String, org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration> redisCacheConfigurations,
                                     final MetricRegistry metricRegistry) throws Exception {
        final var redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder
                .fromConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory)
                .transactionAware()
                .disableCreateOnMissingCache()
                .withInitialCacheConfigurations(redisCacheConfigurations)
                .build();
        redisCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();

        final var rawRedisCacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        rawRedisCacheManager.setCaches(ImmutableList.of(
                ((TransactionAwareCacheDecorator) redisCacheManager.getCache(appId + '-' + quoteCacheNamespace)).getTargetCache(),
                ((TransactionAwareCacheDecorator) redisCacheManager.getCache(appId + '-' + fxCacheNamespace)).getTargetCache())
        );
        rawRedisCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet();

        return InstrumentedCacheManager.instrument(rawRedisCacheManager, metricRegistry);
    }

    private org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration quotesRedisCache(final RedisTemplate quoteRedisTemplate) {
        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        final Duration expiration = Duration.ofSeconds(redisQuotesCacheExpiryMinsDefault * 60L);
        return org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                                                                           .disableKeyPrefix()
                                                                           .disableCachingNullValues()
                                                                           .entryTtl(expiration)
                                                                           .disableCachingNullValues()
                                                                           .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(quoteRedisTemplate.getKeySerializer()))
                                                                           .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(quoteRedisTemplate.getValueSerializer())
                                                                           );
    }
```